# How can I enable checkboxes for custom post type posts on their post list - Wordpress

Tags: posts, list

I have a custom post type called gr-item created by a Wordpress theme. However, checkboxes in Title column for custom post type posts on post list are disabled.

How can I enable them?

Any quick advice is very appreciated.

Regards

No Checkboxes before each Title of custom post type post. Please see the link below:

https://imgur.com/a/QOa1CWh

Comment: Are you talking about the checkboxes in the admin used for bulk actions? Or something different on the front end?

Comment: Hi Jacob Peattie
Yes, checkboxes in Title column for custom post type posts on post list page at Admin backend. my question has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

To enable checkboxes for custom post type posts on their post list in WordPress, you can achieve this by adding some code to your theme's `functions.php` file or by creating a custom plugin. Here's how to do it:

1. Open your theme's `functions.php` file or create a custom plugin.
2. Add the following code to enable checkboxes for your custom post type (replace `'gr-item'` with your actual custom post type name if different):

```php
function enable_custom_post_type_checkboxes($post_type) {
    if ($post_type === 'gr-item') {
        return 'page';
    }
    return $post_type;
}
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'enable_custom_post_type_checkboxes');
add_filter('manage_pages_columns', 'enable_custom_post_type_checkboxes');
```

This code filters the column list for both posts and pages and enables checkboxes for the `'gr-item'` custom post type.

3. Save the changes to your `functions.php` file or activate your custom plugin.

Now, when you go to the post list in your WordPress dashboard for your custom post type `'gr-item'`, you should see checkboxes next to each post title, allowing you to perform bulk actions and interact with the posts.

However, it's worth mentioning that there may be specific code in your third-party theme that is preventing the checkboxes from displaying, so the only way to know if this will work is to try it out. Best of luck to you!

Comment: dear Will Ashworth, as simple as that! I tested your codes, but no checkboxes are displayed or enabled on my CPT list. Many thanks for your help.